# Data factory - copy data with mongodb

Tags: mongodb, azure-data-factory

I have the following doubt in a datafactory pipeline, I have the cosmosbdmongobd connection and I am trying to know how many documents I have before copying to the datalake but I have not been able to do the filter in data factory, in visual studio I know what to do this way db.rips.find().count(); but in data factory this doesn't work for me, is there a way to do it from the pipeline?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

> I am trying to know how many documents I have before copying to the datalake.

There is no proper way to query and fond the no of document in collection from ADF.

And the `Lookup`, `Get metadata` activity which can be used to retrieve metadata from database or files are also not supported for `Cosmos DB MongoDB API`.

**Filter** option in `Cosmos DB MongoDB API` is mainly used to filter the documents based on specific value or condition.

> Specifies selection filter using query operators. To return all documents in a collection.

The workaround can be possible by upserting data in same collection and get the data read from source.

[image]

[image]

set variable to get read rows from output of copy activity.

[image]

[image]

Then you can perform your copy activity to copy data from `Cosmos DB MongoDB API` to `data lake`.